# ScrollView: Problems with height and scrolling

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a `<ScrollView />`. In the [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview) it says

> Keep in mind that ScrollViews must have a bounded height in order to work, since they contain unbounded-height children into a bounded container (via a scroll interaction). In order to bound the height of a ScrollView, either set the height of the view directly (discouraged) or make sure all parent views have bounded height.

This is my markup:

```
<View
    style={{
        paddingLeft: 15,
        paddingRight: 15,
        width: '100%',
        height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
        alignItems: 'center'
    }}>
    <Foo /> // Custom Component with specific height
    <ScrollView
        style={{width: '100%'}}
        ...
        {foo.map((obj, index) => {
            return <View
                key={index}
                style={{
                    display: 'flex',
                    width: '100%',
                    paddingTop: 2,
                    paddingBottom: 2,
                }}
                ...
            </View>
        })
        }
    </ScrollView >
</View>
```

In my markup, I have set the height of the parent `<View />` with `Dimensions.get...`. But the `<ScrollView />` is not scrolling all the way to the bottom.
Why is the `<ScrollView />` not behaving as expected? I want to be able to scroll all the way down and see all the elements.

Answer (score 0):

make shure ScrollView has `flex: 1` set in style props.

> Forgetting to transfer {flex: 1} down the view stack can lead to errors here, which the element inspector makes quick to debug.